# Admin Menu Vanished in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I was installing some modules in Drupal 7.  Suddenly, the helpful buttons across the top for admin mode disappeared.  Can anyone tell me what happened and what I have to do?

I am able to go to {website}/admin and essentially see the same buttons on the page that, I guess, I would see across the top of the page, but I wonder if I am missing out on some functionality.

But even if I still have the functionality, I still can not find the place where I can install new modules, and the system is telling me I need the "views" module to view some content I need to manage.

What do I heed to have enabled in the modules to view these buttons across the top?  Is it called "dashboard"?

Also, if I never find a way to see these buttons, where is the page that will let me add a new module?

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand what exactly do you mean. Which buttons? The black admin toolbar?

Dashboard is a module for creating a special page with different admin view blocks.

Anyway, the page for modules administration is available on /admin/modules in Drupal 7.

Answer (score 0):

I think your administrative toolbar is not visible. 
Check whether the module named `Toolbar` is deactivated in `admin/modules`. If Yes, Turn it on. It will solve your problem.

If not solved, kindly explain your issue.